# xslt choose when not part of a list

Tags: xslt, foreach, .when

I  have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
   <pi:company>
      <pi:employee>
         <pi:name>John</pi:name>
         <pi:division>Accounting</pi:division>
      </pi:employee>
      <pi:employee>
         <pi:name>Will</pi:name>
         <pi:division>IT</pi:division>
      </pi:employee>
      <pi:employee>
         <pi:name>Robert</pi:name>
         <pi:division>Finance</pi:division>
      </pi:employee>
   </pi:company>
</pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
```

I would like to use for-each loop to iterate all employees that don't work in  Accounting nor IT department. I use this code for that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees/pi:company">

        <xsl:for-each select="pi:employee[pi:division !=('Accounting','IT')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="pi:name"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it outputs all the employees, is it possible to change the select in for-each statement to get what I want. I would like to use negation there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"pi:employee[not(pi:division =('Accounting','IT'))]` to express that the division is neither `Accounting` nor `IT`.